# XPages / CSS / Bootstrap Issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, xpages

Hopefully a simple one to answer and just me getting tunnel vision...

I have a button defined as `<xp:button value="Back" id="button1" styleClass="btn-test-header">`

But when rendered, it outputs the class as `class="btn-test-header btn btn-default"`

Why and how is it always appending btn btn-default? Not matter what class I give it, in the browser, it always get this style.....

I have nothing in my theme to say always use that class......

Comment: Please include the hierarchy of themes used, specifically which IBM theme is being applied (e.g. `bootstrap3_flat`, `webstandard`. This specifies which renderers get applied and this what raw HTML gets outputted.

Comment: Hi Paul, I use one theme, which as you've guessed, extends bootstrap3_flat

Comment: It's probably a default translation of xp:button to add those classes

Comment: But if I'm explicitly setting a class, should this not take precedence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap3_flat.theme has the following settings:

```
<!-- XPages Buttons -->
<control>
    <name>Button</name>
    <property mode="concat">
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>btn btn-default</value>
    </property>
</control>

<control>
    <name>Button.Command</name>
    <property mode="concat">
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>btn btn-default</value>
    </property>
</control>

<control>
    <name>Button.Submit</name>
    <property mode="concat">
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>btn btn-primary</value>
    </property>
</control>

<control>
    <name>Button.Default</name>
    <property mode="concat">
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>btn btn-default</value>
    </property>
</control>

<control>
    <name>Button.Cancel</name>
    <property mode="concat">
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>btn btn-default</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

See https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/master/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap/src/com/ibm/xsp/theme/bootstrap/themes/Bootstrap3_flat.theme#L238. If you override these settings in your theme, that may address it, I'm not sure.

Comment: This is great Paul, thanks. Overriding the theme isn't really the way I'd like to go, as across the application, I do use the default button class. I was just a little bit stumped as to why the extra class names were getting appended to my my custom style applied to buttons. It doesn't seem to be an issue, as my styles are the ones getting applied and overriding the default, but it just looked a bit messy when I was inspecting the elements, and seeing loads of styles being loaded but disabled. Thanks